# Stand-alone shared_ptr<T> implementation?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Does anyone know of an open-source, standalone implementation of TR1 `shared_ptr` (and maybe other smart pointers) that I can use in my programs?

---

#### Note:

*"Standalone implementation of `shared_ptr`"* means **`shared_ptr` *itself* needs to be standalone.**
**Not just** the including library.

*So please, **no Boost**!*

Comment: Have you checked your compiler implementation? It might have `shared_ptr` already implemented inside the `std::tr1` namespace.

Comment: You will then have to check what implementations of `shared_ptr` (tr1 or boost libs) can actually be compiled in that environment. Not all *old* compilers can process templates correctly (or the atomic operations that are present in `shared_ptr` for the reference counts...)

Comment: Before you complain about the 2MB worth of Boost headers, please consider that the Boost shared pointer offers you a significant amount of quality; in particular, it is thread-safe. Since all the atomic primitives that are required for that are also taken from Boost, the code naturally grows, but this shouldn't be a problem in the compiled result. If you wanted to write something of similar quality and with the same generality (type-erasing allocators and deleters), you'd have a *lot* of work, and code, on your hands. So why duplicate efforts?

Comment: @Kerrek: The code *naturally grows*? Why do I **possibly** need `preprocessor/list/fold_right.hpp` for `shared_ptr.hpp`, may I ask? If this was 5 header files, I'd understand. Or 10. But 231 is a little ridiculous for a **single** class...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because Boost factors and reuses. Sure, if you wrote this from scratch, you *could* wrap all the necessary ingredients up much tighter, but why bother if they're used widely across the library. As a result, you get high-quality components that are thoroughly tested and as universal and flexible as possible. Check out how much the `atomic` header pulls in, sure, that's a lot, but that's fine.

Comment: @David: "Take at least the effort to read the links"? I not only did that, but I **used** the program, *that's how I knew* its result is too bloated. Also note: ***I never said Boost is not standalone***. I said **its `shared_ptr` implementation is not standalone**, which is a fact -- there are 230 other headers providing support to `shared_ptr`. Did I really deserve downvotes for saying this? Or did people get offended that I said I didn't want Boost?

Comment: @Kerrek: *Surely* people can see why I would get annoyed at seeing something irrelevant like `fold_right` in my `shared_ptr` implementation, no?

Comment: @David: Yes, I believe you. No, I don't believe that means anything. Notice I said **nothing** about the *binary*. Why? Because I feel like *source code is part of a program*, and if someone needs to compile my program with the same compiler, they need 3 MB worth of extra baggage, so in effect *my program is 3 MB big*. Simply put, *I do not want this*, that's all.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Just out of curiosity, what development platform are you working on where 3M is still a problem?

Comment: @David: Does it really matter, and do I really need to explain? Are you meaning to say that [all these people are crazy to ask for solutions without Boost these days?](http://google.com/search?q="without+boost"+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: +1 to counteract the downvoters. This is a well-written/researched question, even it it is misguided.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I was just curious, if you cannot or don't want to provide the information is fine. I only intended to take a look at the rationale behind the decision, so as to understand under which circumstances this might have an impact

Comment: @Mehrdad: Your compiler's tr1 implementation may already contain `shared_ptr`. If not, you can use the the implementation in GNU libstdc++ ([here](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr1/shared_ptr.h?revision=169421&view=markup)).

Comment: @Mehrdad: I haven't looked at it in detail, but [yasper](http://yasper.sourceforge.net/) might meet your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

The boost implementation of `shared_ptr` is entirely header-only, so installing boost to use it is as simple as downloading boost and adding it to your compiler's header search paths. This is no harder with boost than with any other stand-alone implementation. If you want to extract just the `shared_ptr` component to make a separate distribution, then you can use [Boost BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/bcp/index.html).

Comment: You *are* joking, right? I need to copy 1.94 MB worth of headers (that's 231 files) just to used `scoped_ptr`? It seems like you missed the word **standalone** in my question. :(

Comment: You forgot about the multiple megabytes worth of compiler and linker binaries.  Something else you don't ship along with your program.  The argument is nonsense of course :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: What is the actual problem of adding 2M of sources? Only the bits that you use will be added to the actual program, which means that it will only impact your development box (or that of the people developing). Not a problem really. Even if that is a problem, Boost BCP (mentioned in the answer) is a tool to extract bits of the library into a separate tree (i.e. it will remove most of the 2M, not all, will probably leave some bits that are used by `shared_ptr.hpp` --think of compiler configuration and other bits of auxiliary code)

Comment: @Mehrdad - I just ran `bcp shared_ptr` on boost 1.47.0, and the result is a 3.7MB folder that compresses down to 147KB. What makes you think that any other implementation would be significantly smaller?

Comment: @Mehrdad - If the size really bothers you, then you can go through the result of `bcp shared_ptr` and remove all the unnecessary code, and maintain a slim parallel distribution. I don't think that it would be too much effort.

Comment: @David: The fact that *"it will only impact your development box (or that of the people developing)"* is "not a problem"? Maybe not for you, but it ***is*** a problem for me. And when I'm asking for a requirement that Boost can't meet, it doesn't matter how gorgeous Boost is -- it's simply irrelevant to my question.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If that space is a problem, then you can try pulling out headers from the library. Remove, for example, everything that is not related to your particular platform. Understand where the preprocessor lib is used and try to remove it (my guess: `make_shared`). If you can make do without `make_shared` you might be able to remove quite a bit of code from there. You might still be able to start with just `shared_ptr.hpp`, edit it to remove dependencies and then use BCP to pull the dependencies that you did not manage to remove.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the `make_shared` suggestion, I'll try and take a look at it. But I have a feeling doing all that would take a while -- I might as well write my own implementation of `shared_ptr`, it might well be easier and I might learn something in the process as well. I guess my question was more like, "Has anyone else *already done* this?" so that I don't have to spend so much duplicated effort on it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't know how long it will take to clean up the headers (you might even want to start in a different point, for example in a later version of the same compiler and backport the pieces of the STL (from TR1, backporting from C++0x would be a pain). As to implementing your own, there are a few corner cases, and potential problems that are already solved in any prepacked solution, including multithreading guarantees. I would first try to strip the boost headers, giving at least half a day to that approach, and only fall back to a handrolled version if that is too hard.

Comment: "Use `bcp` to take only what you need"? With Boost, that's not actually possible. I've seen things as basic as, say, _optional_ (that can be easily implemented as a piece of code from the Wikibooks on idioms) include about half of the rest of Boost code, including things like Preprocessor...

Comment: @LuisMachuca: Sure -- it's not ideal, but in exchange you get code which is highly tested and complete, and which works with virtually any C++ compiler (no surprise that Preprocessor is useful for that). Could you provide a link to the page(s) on Wikibooks which include an implementation of Optional; I couldn't find it.

Comment: Not saying you don't get quality code, just saying that you don't get "just what you asked", which seems to be one of the main promises Boost makes. Ie.: not a _toolkit_ but a _toolbox_. In fact, my current toolkit **is**, pretty much, code from Boost 1.42 refactored with interdependencies removed or simplified. It works wonders for things like `scoped_ptr` or string algorithms... As for the Optional impl, thanks for making me notice! It was not that but move constructor [(movable resources)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Move_Constructor) instead.

Comment: It's a sin people can't take the OP at his word about "No boost". I've struggled 10 ways to Sunday with Boost on Solaris 10. Boost isn't compatible with Solaris Studio 12.3 and 12.4 so I am in the same boat as the OP and neither will BCP help me.

Comment: @guru_florida: If you are on a platform that doesn't actually support standard C++, that is a different question. A generic "how to implement your own `shared_ptr` in C++" answer won't help you there anyway; since it could very well use features that are missing or broken on your compiler.

Answer (score 5):

You can hack the sharedptr.h header in wxWidgets pretty easily to remove the few macro dependencies (assert, "explicit" keyword, etc.). You then need to replace or remove the atomic inc/dec of the internal reference counting variable. Rename the template and stick it in a namespace. Then you'll have a single-file stand-along version of shared_ptr.

This has the advantage that the source you are modifying has had some wide usage and peer review.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Boost BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/bcp/index.html) to extract components from Boost.

Comment: You *are* joking, right? That's in no way "standalone". I need to copy 1.94 MB worth of headers (that's 231 files) just to used `scoped_ptr`? It seems like you missed the word **standalone** in my question. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: It is standalone. You might be able to reduce the file count manually, but given that 2MB are laughable today i don't see why it would matter.

Comment: @George: Boost is indeed standalone. **Its implementation of `scoped_ptr` isn't.** Those are two different concepts. Also, what doesn't matter to you indeed *does* matter to me (for reasons which I may or may not need to explain on StackOverflow), so I find your argument rather self-centered, unfortunately.

Comment: FYI, [I'm not the only person in the world who sometimes wants to avoid Boost](http://www.google.com/search?q="without+boost"+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Mehrdad: bcp makes `shared_ptr` stand-alone. If you have specific size-restrictions, can't use Boost for a specific reason etc., you should specify in the question what exactly you are looking for. Thinking we can telepathically find out what you need is what is self-centered.

Comment: How in the world does *"bcp make `shared_ptr` stand-alone"*? `shared_ptr.hpp` still can't stand alone in my project...

Comment: @Mehrdad: It extracts shared_ptr and it's dependencies for you so you can use it without the whole of Boost. What else is your definition of stand-alone? Wether it does do the job as good as it could is a different matter.

Comment: My definition of "standalone" is literally that it should **stand alone**. The fact that `shared_ptr` (the class) or `shared_ptr.hpp` (the file) can't stand alone in my project *by definition* makes it not standalone. Sorry if this feels complicated, English is my second language but either way, I definitely didn't think it would be so confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Huh, I guess something I made myself might be even better than `shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename T>
class auto_
{
    T *pValue;
    mutable const auto_<T> *pPrev, *pNext;

public:
    auto_()           : pValue(new T()),  pPrev(NULL), pNext(NULL) { }
    auto_(T *pValue)  : pValue(pValue),   pPrev(NULL), pNext(NULL) { }
    auto_(const T &v) : pValue(new T(v)), pPrev(NULL), pNext(NULL) { }

    auto_(const auto_<T> &o) : pValue(o.pValue), pPrev(&o), pNext(NULL)
    { o.pNext = this; }

    virtual ~auto_()
    {
        const auto_<T> *const pPrev = this->pPrev, *const pNext = this->pNext;
        if (pPrev != NULL) { pPrev->pNext = pNext; }
        if (pNext != NULL) { pNext->pPrev = pPrev; }
        if (pPrev == NULL && pNext == NULL) { delete this->pValue; }
        this->pPrev = this->pNext = NULL;
        this->pValue = NULL;
    }

    auto_<T>& operator=(const auto_<T>& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            this->~auto_();
            this->pValue = other.pValue;
            this->pPrev = &other;
            this->pNext = other.pNext;
            if (other.pNext != NULL) { other.pNext->pPrev = this; }
            other.pNext = this;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    operator   T&() { return *this->pValue; }
    operator   T*() { return  this->pValue; }
    T* operator->() { return  this->pValue; }
    T& operator *() { return *this->pValue; }

    operator   const T&() const { return *this->pValue; }
    operator   const T*() const { return  this->pValue; }
    const T* operator->() const { return  this->pValue; }
    const T& operator *() const { return *this->pValue; }

};
```

Sample usage:

```
template<typename T>
T recurse(T value, int depth)
{
    if (depth > 0) { T result = recurse(value, depth - 1); return result; }
    else { return value; }
}

auto_<int> test()
{
    printf("Value: %d\n", *recurse(auto_<int>(10), 3));
    auto_<int> p1 = recurse<auto_<int> >(5, 3);
    printf("Value: %d\n", *p1);
    auto_<int> p2 = 3;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = p1;
    return p2;
}
```

It looks easier to use than `shared_ptr`, IMHO.

Does it have any pitfalls which I missed (aside from the obvious thread-unsafety)?

Any (constructive) criticism appreciated.

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I just thought I'd also post it here because it's also a (partial) answer for my question. Might try that later, after I refine it a bit; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for such a thing myself --- like you, I have a project where including huge wads of Boost is totally unacceptable.

I've found this:

http://www.lri.fr/~marc/EO/eo/doc/html/shared__ptr_8h-source.html

I have no idea of the code quality, as it's GPL2 which means I can't use it in my proprietary code, but it seems to have no dependencies. But it does seem to be an answer to your question.